# What are some fast ways to install same apks on 400 android tablet?

Tags: installation, tablet, apk

I work at a school who wants to implement a modern education system with tablets.
There will be around 400 tablet all should have a few applications installed for students to use.

I'm planning to have the apps as apk and install them but this will definitely take a lot of time. Is there any way you would advise me to? Can I upload them online and have the tablets in some kind of way to automatically install them online?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into G Suite or some other enterprise management solution to remotely install and manage apps.